# How to make a web page to totally display when loaded in python selenium?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

The main objective I have is to read a table in a webpage and account for the total element it has. But since you have to scroll down to find another elements not 'chased' by this sentece

```
table_css=driver.find_elements_by_id('DeletButtn')
```

then I decided to zoom in down to 30% to catch them all. But no way I've used is working when trying to zoom in:

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style_zoom='30%'")
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='30%'")
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='0.3'")
```

do not work

I have also tried to use key and send keys, but they have been worthless too:

```
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
html.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT)
driver.Keys(html, "ctrl").Keys(html, "-").perform()

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.SUBTRACT).perform()
```

None of these combinations have worked up til now. They haven't show me any error so far, so I do not know what I am doing wrong. 
I am using python 2.7, geckodriver and Firefox

Thanks for your help and greetings!